# Hide a column if the same value is repeated across all rows

Tags: python, pandas

here is a sample data.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np

audit_trail = """\
1|2|ENQ-wbrProcess.php|bus_departures|BUS_SERVICE_NO#DEPARTURE_TM|54790#01/12/2010|BOOKING_STATUS|O|L|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:42:32
5|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|BUS_TYPE_CD||DO|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:27
9|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|EFFECTIVE_FROM||2010-12-02 00:00:00|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:28
13|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|MAX_CHANCE_SEATS||0|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:28
17|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|SCHEDULED_NO||15|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:29
21|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|TRIP_NATURE||Basic|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:29
25|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|PARCEL_SERVICE||N|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:30
29|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|TRIP_NO||S11308|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:30
33|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_services|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|IS_AVL_RESERVATION||N|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:31
37|0|DTO-transfer.php|bus_service_seats|BUS_SERVICE_NO|159734|BUS_SERVICE_NO||159734|PHRTD|2010-12-01 12:43:32"""

col_list = ['transaction_id', 'request_id', 'table_name', 'table_unique_field', 'table_unique_value', 'field_name', 'old_value', 'new_value', 'client_id', 'client_type', 'transaction_date']
audit = pd.read_csv(StringIO(audit_trail), sep="|" , names = col_list, index_col='transaction_date' )

In [44]: audit.client_type.nunique()
Out[44]: 1
```

This will return the rows if client type is "PHRTD"

```
audit[(audit.client_type == 'PHRTD')] [['old_value', 'client_type']]
```

If the unique count of client_type is 1 then show both the columns or else show only 1 column (old_value). Something like this will not work:

```
audit[(if(audit.client_type.nunique() != 1), [['old_value', 'client_type'], ['old_value']])]
```

I am looking for a simple technique to hide the columns where the same value is repeated across all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def trim(df):
    columns = [col for col in df if df[col].nunique() != 1]
    return df[columns]

print(trim(audit.loc[audit.client_type == 'PHRTD', ['old_value', 'client_type']]))
```

yields

```
                              old_value
transaction_date                       
2010-12-01 12:42:32      BOOKING_STATUS
2010-12-01 12:43:27         BUS_TYPE_CD
2010-12-01 12:43:28      EFFECTIVE_FROM
2010-12-01 12:43:28    MAX_CHANCE_SEATS
2010-12-01 12:43:29        SCHEDULED_NO
2010-12-01 12:43:29         TRIP_NATURE
2010-12-01 12:43:30      PARCEL_SERVICE
2010-12-01 12:43:30             TRIP_NO
2010-12-01 12:43:31  IS_AVL_RESERVATION
2010-12-01 12:43:32      BUS_SERVICE_NO
```

---

Tip:

```
audit[(audit.client_type == 'PHRTD')] [['old_value', 'client_type']]
```

uses chained indexing. This is fine for *accessing* data, but may fail when *assigning* new values to `audit`:

```
audit[(audit.client_type == 'PHRTD')] [['old_value', 'client_type']] = values  # would FAIL to modify audit
```

So it is best to avoid [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail) when possible. In this case you could avoid it by using `audit.loc`:

```
audit.loc[audit.client_type == 'PHRTD', ['old_value', 'client_type']] = values
```